# Queue with std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, queue

How can I improve this code?

```
template<class T>
class Queue {
public:
    Queue(const std::initializer_list<T>& i) :elem{i} {}
    int size() const {
        return elem.size();
    }
    bool empty() const {
        return elem.empty();
    }
    void enqueue(T&&);
    void dequeue();
    T peek();
    T& operator[](std::size_t);
    typename std::vector <T>::iterator begin() {
        return elem.begin();
    }
    typename std::vector <T>::iterator end() {
        return elem.end();
    }

private:
    std::vector<T> elem;
};

template<class T>
void Queue<T>::enqueue(T&& t) {
    elem.push_back(t);
}

template<class T>
void Queue<T>::dequeue() {
    if (empty()) {
        throw std::out_of_range("underflow");
    }
    elem.erase(elem.begin());
}

template<class T>
T Queue<T>::peek() {
    if (empty()) {
        throw std::out_of_range("underflow");
    }
    return elem.front();
}

template<class T>
T& Queue<T>::operator[](std::size_t i) {
    if (empty() || i < 0 || i >= size()) {
        throw std::out_of_range("underflow");
    }
    return elem[i];
}
```

Comment: use `std::queue<T>` instead?  Then you get iterators too.

Comment: Or [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) if you need efficient insertion/removal at both ends.

Comment: good point, especially since `std::queue` by default just wraps a `std::deque`.  I achieved substantial performance improvements recently by replacing a `queue` with a `deque`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that you are familiar with [`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) and [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) and wrote this class as a [reinventing-the-wheel](/questions/tagged/reinventing-the-wheel) exercise.

There are a few mainly aesthetic points that you could improve:

- `int size()` is better if returning a `std::size_t`, which is the underlying type returned by `vector::size()`.
- Keep parameter names in function prototypes, it helps self-documenting the code.
- `T peek()` doesn't change any internal state, so it should be `const` too.
- `operator[]` should be provided with two overloads, const and non-const:

  ```
    T& operator[](std::size_t index);
    const T& operator[](std::size_t index) const;
  ```

Otherwise you won't be able to access data in a `const Queue<T>`. The same thing applies to `begin()/end()`. You will have to provide both const and non-const versions. This is purely boilerplate code, but C++ doesn't offer a better solution.

- This excessively long name: `typename std::vector <T>::iterator` should be replaced by a typedef or using alias:

  ```
    using iterator = std::vector<T>::iterator;

    // Then you simply use `iterator` now:
    iterator begin() { ... }
  ```
- Shouldn't you provide a constructor that takes no arguments? It is very likely that you will want to declare an empty queue at some point. A default constructor should also do:

  ```
    Queue() = default;
  ```